# Hot to jump to source from console in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

For SciTE and IDEA, this is not a problem

[image: JetBrains]

But Visual Studio console can't do it

[image: Visual Studio]

I've been looking for Google for a long time and I can't find the answer.

Comment: This looks like a regular windows console.

Comment: @user7860670
Yes, it's easy to see.

Comment: Have you tried using actual terminal embedded in VS?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, its not possible for CMD to use hyperlinks. That's why you can't do this.

Comment: So in the development of vc++ program, how to solve this demand?Pure manual?

Comment: I guess so. As far as I can see, you are writing info messages to console output. Neither command promt, not powershell support navigating hyperlinks from itself. Even putting your output directly to IDE output window probably won't solve your demand coz all output windows are based on powershell.